# Как передать значение в форму (python django)

Tags: python, django, django-model

У меня есть 2 модели. Сard и Client. Отношение у них один ко многим. Моя задача, реализовать регистрацию Client и чтобы автоматический к нему создавалась карта с рандомно заполненными значениями. Я только на стадии изучения django и не знаю как это реализовать. Буду очень благодарен за примеры кода с описанием.

models.py

```
class Card(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False, verbose_name='номер')
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False, verbose_name='пинкод')
    money = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0, verbose_name='деньги')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number


class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, verbose_name='имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, verbose_name='фамилия')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, verbose_name='отчество')
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='карта')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name} {self.middle_name}'
```

forms.py

```
from TIbank.models import Client, Card


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        exclude = 'card',
```

views.py

```
def authorization(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        'form': PostForm()
    }
    return render(request, 'TIbank/authorization.html', context=context)
```

Я пытался создавать отдельно карту и передавать ее в Client. Но ловил ошибку.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас модель не правильно сформирована. По моделям у вас у одной карты может быть несколько клиентов, а логично как раз таки наоборот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью сигналов:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Client)
def create_random_card(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # проверяем, что у объекта нет ключа,
    # т.е. что это именно создание, а не модификация
    if not instance.pk:             
       card = Card.objects.create(
            number = ...,           # тут должны быть значения полей
            pin_code = ...)
       instance.card = card
```

Сигналы позволяют делать действия в определенные моменты. В данном случае сигнал `pre_save`, т.е. он срабатывает перед сохранением объекта, в данном случае `Client`. `instance` - это объект, который будет сохранен. Мы ему тут назначаем карту, которую тут же и создали.